# How to grep and modify the environment variable from a file in linux?

Tags: linux, sed, grep, cut

```
# input file.yaml
conda_name: "test"
user_name: "foo"
```

How do I can the get user_name variable and export to local environment variable (without installing extra packages)? I do not know how to export the variable

```
# where I am stuck
 grep 'user_name:' file.yaml | sed 's/:/=/g'
# export the variable
```

Please feel free to use the approach that you think is the best.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a simple `bash` loop:

```sh
while IFS=': ' read -r k v; do
   [[ $k = "user_name" ]] && declare -x $k="${v//\"/}"
done < file

echo "user_name"

foo
```

`declare -x $k="${v//\"/}"` exports a variable named `$k` which is `user_name`. `${v//\"/}` strips double quotes present in your input file around `foo`.